# How to hard copy List<List<>> in java?

Tags: java, list, copy

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<List<Integer>> ll1 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
     ll1.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(1));
     System.out.println(ll1.get(0));
     //hard copy don't work
     List<List<Integer>> ll2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(ll1);
     System.out.println(ll2.get(0) == ll1.get(0));
}
```

Except using for loop to do hard copy for every inner list, do we have another way to do hard copy.
Could you explain how `List<List<Integer>> ll2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(ll1);` work and why it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to copy the inner lists:

```
private List<List<Integer>> copy(List<List<Integer>> toCopy) {
    List<List<Integer>> copy = new ArrayList<>(toCopy.size());
    for(List<Integer> inner : toCopy) {
        copy.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(inner));
    }
    return copy;
}
```